# Does a definite limit exist for how much noise a Kalman Filter kan correctly filter?

Tags: algorithms, filters, kalman-filter

I cannot really find scientific research about this, but here is my explanation.
Let's say for instance you have a row of 10 times a boolean number.

```
0000010000
```

Let's assume that that single '1' is a false prediction.
How short can this sequence of booleans get before a Kalman Filter cannot filter it anymore?
Is there a definite limit (like ~66.6% accurate data)?
Please provide with paper if this exists.

Comment: That is just $1$ boolean number. A row of $10$ boolean numbers would mean $10$ (not necessarely) different boolean numbers.

Comment: @DavideTrono that's not true. A boolean number is either a 1 or a 0.

Comment: Nope. That would mean $1234567890$ are $10$ numbers in base $10$, which is clearly not true.

Comment: @DavideTrono I have rephrased it.

Comment: The theory of Kalman filters deals with real (or possibly complex) valued signals and not Boolean. In practice those signals can be quantized, but that does violates some assumptions maybe making the filter not exactly optimal. Or does your sequence of binary value represent a binary number?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I understand, but I wanted to make it abstract as much as possible. In my mind adding real numbers to an example would make it a little bit messier. I do understand this may create some confusion for what I am asking. I am just wondering how much noise is too much noise to filter (e.g. Kalman Filter).

Comment: Any finite noise level can be filtered by a Kalman filter. Do note that the filtered signal is still noisy, just less so than the input. If the noise level is very high could mean that the filtered signal could still be too noisy for your liking. Here the computed state covariance is an indication of the output noise level.